# Is it possible to recover an enclosing instance from a projection type in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose we have...

```scala
class Outer(val name : String):
  class Inner:
    def thump = s"${name}'s heartbeat"
```

We want to write a function that accepts the Inner of any, possibly unknown, outer. Easy peasy with projection types!

```scala
def stethoscope( inner : Outer#Inner ) = inner.thump
```

This works fine, and obviously depends upon `inner` retaining a reference to its enclosing instance.

But then is it possible to write a function like

```scala
def enclosingInstance( inner Outer#Inner ) : Outer = ???
```

assuming the definition of the classes is outside of our control.

(So we can't add a method to inner referring to a self reference of `Outer`, for example.)

Comment: maybe `enclosingInstance[O <: Outer](inner: O#Inner): Outer`? However, note that the mere notion of writing a method that accepts any `Inner` kind of defeats the idea of path-dependant types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we compile:

```
class Outer(val name : String):
  class Inner:
    def thump = s"${name}'s heartbeat"
```

the definition of inner class could look like:

```
> scala-cli compile --scala "3.3.0" .
Compiling project (Scala 3.3.0, JVM)
Compiled project (Scala 3.3.0, JVM)
> javap -p .scala-build/test2_23be26abb2/classes/main/Outer\$Inner.class
Compiled from "test.scala"
public class Outer$Inner {
  private final Outer $outer;
  public Outer$Inner(Outer);
  public java.lang.String thump();
  public final Outer Outer$Inner$$$outer();
}
```

As we see reference to `$outer: Outer` is `private` so we cannot access it in a "legal" way. `Outer$Inner$$$outer(): Outer` is `public`... but if we tries to call it, compiler don't know such symbol

```
value Outer$Inner$$$outer() is not a member of outer.Inner
```

It makes sense, as it is generated later on, when bytecode is emitted, so e.g. typechecker phase might not know it (or act as it doesn't know it). Scala's internals can use it to access it when the some code would have to access it legally (e.g. in some context where `Outer.this` is legal), but user might not have a legal way to call it.

We could "hack" around this limitation with a runtime reflection:

```
class Outer(val name : String):
  class Inner:
    def thump = s"${name}'s heartbeat"

def enclosingInstance( inner: Outer#Inner ) : Outer =
  val field = inner.getClass.getDeclaredField("$outer")
  field.setAccessible(true)
  field.get(inner).asInstanceOf[Outer]

val outer = new Outer("test")
val inner = new outer.Inner
 
println(outer == enclosingInstance(inner)) // true
```

[See scastie.](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/MFXAdj1GSCG9JB1IEwgTQw)

I wouldn't recommend relying on such tricks - since the name is autogenerated you would have to e.g. list all declared fields and check which of them is:

- `private`
- `final`
- matching `Class[Outer]`

to not rely that this generated name won't change in the future (probably not but I wouldn't bet my salary on it). I would also check if this is really the only way I can obtain `Outer` instance (maybe passing them along with `[O <: Outer](o: Outer, i: o.Inner)` would be possible?).

But if you really have to, you do what you have to do.

Perhaps (I haven't check that) - list of declared definitions visible in Scala 3's compile time reflection would be able to see `Outer$Inner$$$outer()` so maybe `enclosingInstance` could also be  implemented as a macro (similarly to how you cannot manually call methods defining default values for some method, but inside a macro you have an access to these methods - e.g. `def methodname(a: Int = 1)` generates `methodname$default$1` which you cannot call in normal code, but you can call it inside a macro).